# Deprecated function not working in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I'm change the default attributes:

```
const blockAttrs = {
        avatarSize: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 120, // 70 -> 120
        },
        //other attrs
      };
```

Deprecated function:

```
deprecated: [
            {
                attributes: {
                    ...blockAttrs,
                    avatarSize: {
                        type: 'number',
                        default: 70
                    }
                },
                save: function ( { attributes } ) {}
            }
        ]
```

But when i refresh post, block still display error:
[image]

Someone

Comment: Can you post the entire block code?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation from  https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-deprecation/

I think you may need the following

```
 migrate( { text } ) {
            return {
                content: text
            };
        },
```

So in your case:

```
migrate( { avatarSize } ) {
            avatarSize: {
                    type: 'number',
                    default: 70
                }  content: text
            };
        },
```

Hopefully points you in the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

Your save function needs to return a valid React component or null.

```php
save: function ( { attributes } ) {}
```

should be

```php
save: function ( { attributes } ) { return null; }
```

Comment: That sounds plausible, but it's not obvious to me from the question that is the problem. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: ``save: function ( { attributes } ) {}`` should be ``save: function ( { attributes } ) { return null; } ``